# Django-rest: How to implement authentication and permissions for custom User models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-permissions

views.py

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        search_query = self.request.query_params.get('user', None)

        if search_query is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(name__istartswith=search_query)
        queryset = queryset.order_by('name')
        return queryset


class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    model = User
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

models.py

```
class UserRole(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
        db_table = 'userrole'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class User(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
        db_table = 'user'

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='active')
    roleid = models.ForeignKey(UserRole, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               default=None, blank=True, db_column='roleid')
    createdby = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    createdon = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updatedon = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, auto_now=True)
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
class UserRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserRole
```

I've gone through with Django-rest documentation but not able to find a reference for implementing authentication and permission for custom created Users.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Django Document for [User authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/) and [Permissions in Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/).

Below is the sample models structure for custom `BaseUser` and `BaseUserManager`.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class BaseUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, useremail, display_name, password=None):
        if not useremail:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        now = timezone.now()

        user = self.model(useremail=BaseUserManager.normalize_email(useremail))
        user.display_name = display_name
        user.email = useremail
        user.profile_slug = getUniqueValue(BaseUser,slugify(useremail.split("@")[0]),field_name="profile_slug")
        user.set_password(password)
        user.status='A'
        user.last_login = user.date_joined = now
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, useremail, display_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(useremail=useremail,
            display_name=display_name, password=password)
        user.email = useremail
        user.display_name = display_name
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.status='A'
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    profile_slug = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, choices=Gender)
    useremail = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'useremail'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['display_name']
    objects = BaseUserManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.display_name
```

In your **permission.py**, you may define permissions as:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CheckPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    try:
        # some code
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Comment: That documentation is valid when we use auth.user ? Is that correct or we can use it for Custom users as well

Comment: That is valid for custom User as well. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I have added some sample code to define custom `BaseUser` and how to define `Permission` class.